# WinAPI create metro style application issues

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to implement simple metro style window using WinAPI (basicly like Visual Studio 2012 style) to run on Windows 7 and Windows 8, I know it a hard work and at begin, I have those problems:

**1. Create a squared window**
I can achieve this by create a `borderless` window (mean no border, no titlebar, only client area) but by this way, I can't resize this window and titlebar was lost of course. Are these any ways to create a squared corner window and still keep titlebar (including close, max, min, ... buttons)?

**2. Owner draw `close`, `maximize`, `minimize` buttons**
I can owner draw whole titlebar by catching `WM_NCPAINT` event but this way I see these buttons (close, maximize, minimize) go to the hell. How can I show these button in my way (I mean draw it by my ideas)?

**3. Create shadow**
You can see that if Visual Studio 2012's window do not maximized, it show a shadow, it look great and I want apply that effect to my simple window. How can I do that?

Comment: 1&2: You need to write code that draws buttons and handles mouse events.  Good luck.  See also `WM_NCHITTEST`.  3: Create a layered window with a partially transparent background.

Comment: A more fundamental issue is why would you even want to do this? :) Metro is hardly the pinnacle of user interface design.

Comment: @SLaks: Can you give more details in creating layered window with a partially transparent background?

Comment: @BìnhNguyên: Not really.  IIRC, you set an image with alpha channel as the background.  See MSDN.

Comment: @SLaks: Thanks for your quick reply! Could you make this as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your own code that draws basic window elements, and handle mouse events by hand to make them interactive.  (hooking `WM_NCHITTEST` may help for interactivity)

To make a shadow, make your window layered, then set a background image with an alpha-transparent shadow.

Comment: One more question please. I create a window with `WM_POPUPWINDOW` style (drop titlebar for a perfect squared window) and problem is when I return `HTTOP` (or `HTTOPLEFT`, ...) from `WM_NCHITTEST` it not resize window as expect. How to resolve this?

Comment: @BìnhNguyên: I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what SLaks said, which will work but is a lot of effort and will take time, you may want to consider whether you can use a framework in developing your program. If you can, then you may be able to use a framework toolkit to implement the "window chrome" leaving you free to work on the the important part of your application: the **logic**.

If you can use MFC, then I would recommend CodeJock's [Toolkit Pro 2013](http://www.codejock.com/products/toolkitpro/); I am not affiliated with them in any way, but have used their product in the past and it's quite good.

I'm sure that there are other toolkits, some of which might target different frameworks, but I have no experience with them and no basis to recommend them.

Comment: Thanks you!, I do this just for fun only :D